# \emph breaks tabularray when used in collected body content

Tags: tabularray

This is a follow up question regarding: [How to use DTLforeach (datatool) within a tabularray table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638066/how-to-use-dtlforeach-datatool-within-a-tabularray-table/638080#638080).

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{datatool,tabularray,xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\crcEntry}{ o m m }{%
  \def\crcDB{#2}%
  \DTLifdbexists{\crcDB}{}{\DTLnewdb{\crcDB}}%
  \DTLnewrow{\crcDB}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\setkeys{#2}{#3}}{\setkeys{#1}{#3}}%
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{OtherFundingSource}{nameID}{%
  \DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{nameID}{#1}
}
\define@key{OtherFundingSource}{periodStart}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{periodStart}{#1}}
\define@key{OtherFundingSource}{periodEnd}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{periodEnd}{#1}}
\define@key{OtherFundingSource}{projectTitle}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{projectTitle}{#1}}
\define@key{OtherFundingSource}{fundingAgency}{\DTLnewdbentry{\crcDB}{fundingAgency}{#1}}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\crcOtherFundingSourceTable}{  }{%
  \def\tblrbody{}%
  \DTLforeach*{OtherFundingSource}{%
    \nameID=nameID,%
    \fundingAgency=fundingAgency,%
    \projectTitle=projectTitle,%
    \periodStart=periodStart,%
    \periodEnd=periodEnd%
  }{%
    \edef\tblrbody{\tblrbody
      {\nameID}
      & {x}
      & \projectTitle
      & \periodStart --\periodEnd
      & \fundingAgency\\
    }}%
  \begin{tblr}[%
    expand=\tblrbody,
    label={none},
    entry={none},
    long
    ]{
      colspec = {m{2.6cm}m{.8cm}X[m]m{1.3cm}m{2cm}},
    rowhead = 1,
    row{1} = {
      font={\bfseries},
      halign={c}
    },
  }
  PI %
  & Project %
  & Project title %
  & Funding period %
  & Funding agency\\
  \tblrbody
\end{tblr}}

\begin{document}
\crcEntry{OtherFundingSource}{
  nameID = {NAME},
  projectTitle = {This is my \emph{title}.},
  periodStart = {2020},
  periodEnd = {2023},
  fundingAgency = {LaTeX-funding}
}
\crcOtherFundingSourceTable
\end{document}
```

It will give me the error:

> ! Use of \@sDTLforeach doesn't match its definition.
> \text@command #1->\edef \reserved@a {
> \unexpanded {#1}}\ifx \reserved@a @emp...
>
> l.77 \crcOtherFundingSourceTable

But I can compile when I delete `\emph` from the content.

Comment: never use `\edef` on arbitrary text content.  Use `\protected@edef\tblrbody`.

Comment: Perfect! Do you want to turn that into an answer? How do I find out when I have to use `protected`?

Comment: or   `\expandafter\def\expandafter\tblrbody\expandafter{\tblrbody{\nameID}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

never use `\edef` on arbitrary text content.

Use `\protected@edef\tblrbody`.