# Using datatool with tabularray

Tags: tabularray, datatool

This is a followup to or restatement of [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638066/how-to-use-dtlforeach-datatool-within-a-tabularray-table), because I had a great deal of difficulty in understanding both the question and the answer. The example file had a *lot* going on, and I think it'll be easier to understand the answer if we use a simpler example.

So say I have a file, `table.csv`, as follows:

```
FirstName,LastName,Job
Bob,Builder,construction worker
Steve,Wumbo,Politician
Greembo,Flutes,Comedian
```

and a tex file, `main.tex`, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{table}{table.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{}
    First name & Last name & Occupation \\
    \DTLforeach{table}{%
    \firstname=FirstName,\lastname=LastName,\occupation=Job}{%
    \firstname & \lastname & \occupation \\}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this, lualatex fails, giving me the error

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> ...ow\romannumeral \dtlforeachlevel }}\firstname &
                                                   \lastname & \occupation \...

l.15 \end
       {tblr}
```

and spitting out a pretty bad looking table as a result.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

I would really appreciate if the answer were not just a block of code but also included an explanation of the working code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is that `\DTLforeach` is not expanded at the right moment. This is explained in the manual of the `tabularray` package: "In contrast to traditional tabular environment, tabularray environments need to see every `&` and `\\`".

As mentioned in the question, this issue and the solution are similar to the one on [How to use DTLforeach (datatool) within a tabularray table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638066/how-to-use-dtlforeach-datatool-within-a-tabularray-table).

The solution is to first collect the result of `\DTLforeach` in a macro. This macro is initialized with `\tl_new:N \tblrbody`.

Inside `\DTLforeach`, the content is collected with `\tl_build_put_right:Ne`. Here, `\exp_not:V` is used which recovers the content of `\firstname`, `\lastname` and `\occupation` and prevents expansion. This is unnecessary with the provided data but it is necessary if the data would contain for example `\emph{text}`.

This process is started with `\tl_build_begin:N` and ended with `\tl_build_end:N`. Thereafter, the option `expand=\tblrbody` is given to the `tblr` environment where `\tblrbody` is placed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{table}{table.csv}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \tblrbody
\tl_build_begin:N \tblrbody
  \DTLforeach{table}{
    \firstname=FirstName,
    \lastname=LastName,
    \occupation=Job
  }{
    \tl_build_put_right:Ne \tblrbody { \exp_not:V \firstname & \exp_not:V \lastname & \exp_not:V \occupation \\ }
  }
\tl_build_end:N \tblrbody
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{tblr}[expand=\tblrbody]{}
First name & Last name & Occupation\\
\tblrbody
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in here somewhere? It isn't compiling. Undefined control sequence: `...eral \dtlforeachlevel }}\tl_build_put_right:Ne`.

Comment: The command `\tl_build_put_right:Ne` is fairly recent. An option is to update. Another option is to place `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_build_put_right:Nn { Ne }` after `\ExplSyntaxOn`.